# Flutter firease phone not sending sms due to verification sha key error

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I added application signing key, debug sha keys, release sha keys to firebase, while it works in one application, it doesn't work in my other application.

> E/FirebaseAuth(21751): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17028 A safety_net_token was passed, but no matching SHA-256 was registered in the Firebase console. Please make sure that this application’s packageName/SHA256 pair is registered in the Firebase Console.
>
> I/flutter (21751): This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ A safety_net_token was passed, but no matching SHA-256 was registered in the Firebase console. Please make sure that this application’s packageName/SHA256 pair is registered in the Firebase Console. ]

Comment: Generate new SHA key then try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the package name because I was going to put the application on the market. Although the package name did not match with firebase, otp was not working while other functions were working. Deleting the app from Firebase and installing it with the correct package name fixed it

Answer (score 0):

[image]The same I had experienced, what happened was , I have newly install windows , therefore debug SHA keys changed, I added new debug sha1,sha256 ,

to get SHA keys terminal run cd android , then below Code & pressed with ctrl button
./gradlew signingReport,

if this not works
open project level build.gradle, in top left click
open for edit in Android Studio

it will take some time to load
then run  ./gradlew signingReport